# Insert NULL into SQL Server column with Python

Tags: null

i'm using Python 3.9 and extracting data from salesforce.
i want to insert the data into an SQL Server table.
all works fine until one of the fields i want to insert is coming as None (empty).
the SQL Server table has a column with type Float and some records has data for that column and some doesn't (hence, are equal to NULL).

when executing the INSERT statement with no data for "ExpectedRevenue" column ("None") and where the corresponding column is Float andexpecting to get a Float data type (not "None") i get an error such as:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to float. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

the INSERT statement is similar to:

`cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [SOME DB].[dbo].[SOME TABLE] (Id, IsDeleted, Name, ExpectedRevenue) VALUES(?,?,?,?) ''',(Id, IsDeleted, Name,ExpectedRevenue) )`

at the above example the last column is Float at the table, the field names are the same as the variable names.

please assist

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of NaN values in your data. The sql server Null equivalent in python is None object, so you must change all NaNs with None, if you want to insert Nulls into the sql server:
`df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)`

Answer (score 0):

never mind...
my bad but it worked just fine with the "None" insertion